# Congested Mountain Trail

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, queue

I am trying to solve this code challenge:

> There is mountain with a popular hiking trail. At one point on the trail, the path narrows so that only a single hiker can pass through at a time. When several hikers arrive at this point simultaneously two queues can build up one for hikers ascending the mountain and one for hikers descending. It takes each hiker one second to pass completely through the narrow portion of the trail. If all the waiting hikers are all going the same direction (either ascending or descending) then they can immediately begin passing through one at a time, in the order of their arrival. When hikers going in both directions are walking, then local custom dictates the following procedure for determining which hiker has priority and, gets to pass through path. The customs are below:
>
> - If in the previous second, no hiker passed through, then the first waiting, descending hiker gets to go first
> - If in the previous second, a descending hiker passed though, then the first hiker in the descending goes first
> - If in the previous second, an ascending hiker passed through, then the hiker in the ascending queue goes first
>
> For each hiker, find the time when they will pass through the narrow portion of the trail.
>
> #### Function Description
>
> Complete the function `getResult`
>
> `getResult` has the following parameters:
>
> `int arrival[n]`: an array of `n` integers where the value at index `i` is the time in seconds when the `i`<sup>th</sup> hiker arrives at the narrow portion of the trail. If `arrival[i] = arrival[j]` and `i < j` then then hiker `i` arrives before hiker `j`.
>
> `int direction[n]`: an array of `n` integers where the value at index `i` is the direction of the `i`<sup>th</sup> hiker: 0 for ascending and 1 for descending.
>
> Returns:
>
> `int[n]`: An array of `n` integers where the value at index `i` is the time when the `i`<sup>th</sup> hiker will pass through the narrow portion of the trail.

This is the code I have written. It works for the 1<sup>st</sup> test case. However, for the 2<sup>nd</sup> test case its wrong.

```py
def getResult(arrival, direction):
  n = len(arrival)
  result = [0] * n
  last_direction = -1  # -1 represents no hiker passed through in the previous second
  
  i = 0        
  while i < len(arrival):
    ascending_queue = []
    descending_queue = []
    if i == 0:
      if direction[0] == 0:
        #ascending_queue.pop(0)
        result[0] = arrival[0]
        last_direction = 0
      else:
        #descending_queue.pop(0)
        result[0] = arrival[0]
        last_direction = 1
    
    a = i + 1 if i == 0 else i
    chk = False
    while(a + 1 < len(arrival) and arrival[a] == arrival[a+1]):
      if direction[a] == 0:
        ascending_queue.append(a)
      else:
        descending_queue.append(a)
      if direction[a+1] == 0:
        ascending_queue.append(a+1)
      else:
        descending_queue.append(a+1)
      a += 1
      chk = True
      
        
    if ascending_queue and descending_queue:
      if last_direction == 0:
        next_val = i
        idx = ascending_queue.pop(0)
        result[idx] = arrival[i + 1]
        prev = result[idx]
        next_val = max(next_val,idx)
        while ascending_queue:
          idx = ascending_queue.pop(0)
          result[idx] = prev + 1
          last_direction = direction[idx]
          prev = result[idx]
          next_val = max(next_val,idx)
        
        
        while descending_queue:
          idx = descending_queue.pop(0)
          result[idx] = prev + 1
          last_direction = direction[idx]
          prev = result[idx]
          next_val = max(next_val,idx)
        
        i = next_val

      else:
        next_val = i
        idx = descending_queue.pop(0)
        result[idx] = arrival[i + 1]
        prev = result[idx]
        next_val = max(next_val,idx)
        while descending_queue:
          idx = descending_queue.pop(0)
          result[idx] = prev + 1
          last_direction = direction[idx]
          prev = result[idx]
          next_val = max(next_val,idx)
        
        
        while ascending_queue:
          idx = ascending_queue.pop(0)
          result[idx] = prev + 1
          last_direction = direction[idx]
          prev = result[idx]
          next_val = max(next_val,idx)
        
        i = next_val
        
        
    else:
      if chk:
        j = i
        while(arrival[j] == arrival[j+1]):
          result[j] = arrival[i] if j == i else result[j-1] + 1
          j += 1
      else:
        result[i] = arrival[i]
        last_direction = direction[i]
    
    if chk:
      i = a + 1
    else:
      i += 1

  return result


# Example usage:
#arrival = [0, 1, 1, 3, 3]
#direction = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
# Output: [0, 2, 1, 4, 3]

arrival = [0, 0, 1, 4]
direction = [0, 1, 1, 0]
#Ouput = [2, 0, 1, 4]
```

For the 2<sup>nd</sup> test case, my code returns `[0, 0, 1, 4]`. One drawback of my approach is that I am only adding hikers that arrive at the same time but in the 2<sup>nd</sup> case when we process the hiker  at index 1 in descending order, we must then process the hiker at index 2 as they are descending. But my approach would process hiker at index 0 first.

I don't see a different way to do it.

Open to any different/new approaches/languages(Java/C++) or modifications to this approach.

Comment: It would be good to add a link to the code challenge. Both test cases have the arrival times appear in sorted order. Is this always the case? If not, can you provide a test case where this is not so, and the expected output?

Comment: Yeah, the arrival times appear in sorted order always. Don't have a link to the code challenge as its part of my uni coursework that I was unable to solve earlier so was curious to know how I could solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea with two queues is fine, but I would put *all* hikers on these queues, and then pop from them as the time elapses. I would also combine the hiker id (the index in the input lists) with their arrival time in a tuple.

Here is how I would suggest doing it:

```py
def getResult(arrival, direction):
    # Determine a time before which all hikers will have gone through the narrow pass
    max_time = max(arrival) + len(arrival)  
    
    def makeQueue(filter_dir):
        # We rely on the fact that `sorted` implements a *stable* sort
        q = sorted((time, hiker) 
                for hiker, (time, desc) in enumerate(zip(arrival, direction)) 
                if desc == filter_dir)
        # Add a dummy entry to avoid empty queue issues
        q.append((max_time, -1))  
        # Reverse so we can pop from the queue in the right order
        return q[::-1]  
        
    # Put all hikers in one of the two queues, with their id and time of arrival
    queues = [makeQueue(0), makeQueue(1)]  # Ascending hikers, descending hikers
    result = [0] * len(arrival)
    current_time = 0  
    # As long there are hikers that didn't pass through yet... keep going.
    # (NB: each queue has a dummy entry at index 0)
    while len(queues[0]) + len(queues[1]) > 2:  
        # Get the earliest time a hiker arrived or will arrive at the narrow pass
        current_time = max(current_time, min(queues[0][-1][0], queues[1][-1][0]))
        # If there are descending hikers already waiting at the narrow pass, 
        #    then give them priority
        active_queue = queues[queues[1][-1][0] <= current_time]
        # Let all waiting people on the selected side go through the narrow pass.
        while active_queue[-1][0] <= current_time:  # Someone waiting?
            # One hiker walks through the narrow pass
            result[active_queue.pop()[1]] = current_time 
            # One second passes...
            current_time += 1  
    # All hikers went through the narrow pass
    return result
```